# C# call non static method with different instance of a Class

Tags: c#

I want to call a method with different instances of a class dynamicly based on a string

```
Myclass One = new Myclass();
Myclass Tow = new Myclass();
Myclass Three = new Myclass();

string instanceofclass = "Three";

instanceofclass.MyMethod();
```

Comment: put 'em to `Dictionary<string, Myclass>` ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a [Dictionary<TKey,TValue>](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2) where the key is the name and the value the instance:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

Dictionary<string, MyClass> MyClassDictionary
  = new Dictionary<string, MyClass>();

MyClassDictionary.Add("One", new Myclass());
MyClassDictionary.Add("Two", new Myclass());
MyClassDictionary.Add("Three", new Myclass());

string instanceofclass = "Three";

MyClassDictionary[instanceofclass].MyMethod();

MyClassDictionary["One"].MyMethod();
```

In case of you don't really need to have a string as key, you can also use an integer as index, thus it could be a [List<T>](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1):

```
List<MyClass> MyClassList = new List<MyClass>();

MyClassList.Add(new Myclass());
MyClassList.Add(new Myclass());
MyClassList.Add(new Myclass());

MyClassList[2].MyMethod();
```

Comment: You might think I'm a little picky, but `MyClassList[3]` will throw an out of range exception ;) (as indexes go from 0 to 2 in your example)

Comment: @Rafalon "Three"/3 ... not pickly: you have a good eye, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Store references to them in a dictionary

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string,Myclass>{
    ["One"] = new Myclass(),
    ["Two"] = new Myclass(),
    ["Three"] = new Myclass()
};

string instanceofclass = "Three";

dict[instanceofclass].MyMethod();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Factory pattern and create needed class according to your parametr.
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/factory-method-design-pattern-in-c-sharp/